# Spring Boot: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have a SpringBoot app. with these dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    </dependency>

      <!-- Logging dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>    

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.noraui/ojdbc7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.noraui</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But when I run the app. I got this error:

```
2017-10-23 15:09:01.095 ERROR 95375 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@15c43bd9] to prepare test instance [com.traxxeo.interfaces.TelefonicaInterfacesApplicationTests@72057ecf]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107) ~[spring-test-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242) ~[spring-test-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:369) [surefire-junit4-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:275) [surefire-junit4-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:239) [surefire-junit4-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:160) [surefire-junit4-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:373) [surefire-booter-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:334) [surefire-booter-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:119) [surefire-booter-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:407) [surefire-booter-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "prod" are currently active).
```

and I don't know where it comes from because I don't have any class accessing the DB, and I only have 1 test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TelefonicaInterfacesApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

and I got this error since I put the DB dependencies in the pom.xml file, before I could run it without any problem, and it was working fine

Comment: You have the oracle driver in the pom/classpath but don't have any configuration. And Spring Boot got confused if you wan't to use the oracle driver or not. You have to add jdbc url, username, password, etc to the application.proeprties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following code addition to spring-config.xml might resolve the issue:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${DbDriverName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${DbUrl}" />
        <property name="username" value="${DbUsername}" />
        <property name="password" value="${DbPassword}" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your spring boot soliciting doesn’t deal with any database connections for instance application purpose is just to consume a service there is an annotation called enable auto configuration through which you can mention list of thins to exclude.

For ex:
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})